# Performing calculations using powers

Tags: c

Say I have two variables listed below:

```
CLOCK_RATE_A =2;
CPU_TIME_A = 10;
```

Will the following piece of code allow me to perform the calculation 10 * (2*10^9) and assign the result to a new variable?

```
CLOCK_CYCLES_A = CPU_TIME_A * (CLOCK_RATE_A * pow(10, 9));
```

Comment: Did you try it? Why didn't you?

Comment: is there something wrong with your capslock when writing code?

Comment: are they ints? what are you actually asking here?

Comment: I vote... you compile it and find out.

Comment: -1 If you are at a machine that doesn't have a compiler, instead of asking for our time, why not try http://codepad.org/ If you are still stuck, _then_ ask.

Comment: Thanks Idrumm.  Will do in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your data types. If `pow` is *not* the standard C library `pow` function and defined to return an `int`, and your other types are `int` then you will overflow the `int` type on some platforms.

(Note that `pow(10, 9)` is very close to the `int` limit on a 32 bit platform.)

However, if `pow` is implemented as per the standard (i.e. returns a floating point type), then the expression

```
CPU_TIME_A * (CLOCK_RATE_A * pow(10, 9))
```

will be calculated in floating point, and you should set `CLOCK_CYCLES_A` to be a `double` type, or cast to a 64 bit integer if your platform and compiler has one.